# Mask RCNN training on custom dataset hangs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, faster-rcnn

I'm trying to train a Mask RCNN model on a custom dataset. The dataset I use for testing is the kangaroo dataset from https://github.com/experiencor/kangaroo and I'm essentially following this example: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/tree/master/samples/balloon.

I have rewritten some of the code to match the dataset (which is in bounding boxes rather than polygons) (renamed ballon.py to kangaroo.py and only showing changes I made):

```
def xml_annotation_to_dict(src):
    """Takes a source file (xml) and returns a dictionary

    Parameters
    ----------
    src : string
        Path to xml file

    Returns
    -------
    dict

    Example
    -------
    >>> xml_annotation_to_dict('path/to/annotation/file.xml')
    """
    tree = ET.parse(src)
    root = tree.getroot()

    annotation_data = {}
    annotation_data['source'] = src
    annotation_data['image_filename'] = list(root.iterfind('filename'))[0].text
    annotation_data['image'] = {
        'width': int(list(root.iterfind('size/width'))[0].text),
        'height': int(list(root.iterfind('size/height'))[0].text),
        'depth': int(list(root.iterfind('size/depth'))[0].text)
    }
    annotation_data['annotations'] = []
    for annotation in root.iterfind('object'):
        annotation_data['annotations'].append({
            'name': list(annotation.iterfind('name'))[0].text,
            'bbox': {
                'xmin': int(list(annotation.iterfind('bndbox/xmin'))[0].text),
                'ymin': int(list(annotation.iterfind('bndbox/ymin'))[0].text),
                'width': int(list(annotation.iterfind('bndbox/xmax'))[0].text) - int(list(annotation.iterfind('bndbox/xmin'))[0].text),
                'height': int(list(annotation.iterfind('bndbox/ymax'))[0].text) - int(list(annotation.iterfind('bndbox/ymin'))[0].text)
            }
        })
    return annotation_data

class CustomConfig(Config):
    """Configuration for training on the toy  dataset.
    Derives from the base Config class and overrides some values.
    """
    # Give the configuration a recognizable name
    NAME = 'Custom'

    # We use a GPU with 12GB memory, which can fit two images.
    # GPU_COUNT = 0
    # I've set this to 1 and that doesn't seem to work

    # Adjust down if you use a smaller GPU.
    # I've set this to 2 as well, didn't change much
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

    # Number of classes (including background)
    NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 1  # Background + kangaroo

    # Number of training steps per epoch, changed from 100 to 20 to reduce training in this test, didn't change much
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 100

    # Skip detections with < 80% confidence
    DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.8


class KangarooDataset(utils.Dataset):
    def load_kangaroo(self, dataset_dir, subset):
        # Add classes. We have only one class to add.
        self.add_class("kangaroo", 1, "kangaroo")

        # Train or validation dataset?
        assert subset in ["train", "val"]

        # load all filepaths and split deterministically
        # using sklear train_test_split method
        # assume files to be split over "annots" and "images"
        # directories
        images_paths = glob(os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'images', '*.jpg'))
        annotations_paths = glob(os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'annots', '*.xml'))

        images_train_paths, \
        images_test, \
        annotations_train_paths, \
        annotations_test_paths = train_test_split(
            images_paths,
            annotations_paths,
            train_size=0.7,
            test_size=0.3,
            random_state=0)

        if subset == 'train':
            paths = annotations_train_paths
        else:
            # subset == 'val', meaing test
            paths = annotations_test_paths

        # add dictionairy to class containing image and annotations
        for annotation_path in paths:
            annotation_data = xml_annotation_to_dict(annotation_path)

            # create list of polygons per annotation file (can have multiple polygons)
            polygons = []
            for annotation in annotation_data['annotations']:
                ys = [
                    annotation['bbox']['ymin'],
                    annotation['bbox']['ymin'],
                    annotation['bbox']['ymin'] + annotation['bbox']['height'],
                    annotation['bbox']['ymin'] + annotation['bbox']['height']
                ]
                xs = [
                    annotation['bbox']['xmin'],
                    annotation['bbox']['xmin'],
                    annotation['bbox']['xmin'] + annotation['bbox']['width'],
                    annotation['bbox']['xmin'] + annotation['bbox']['width']
                ]
                polygons.append({
                    'ys': ys,
                    'xs': xs
                })

            self.add_image(
                'kangaroo',
                image_id=annotation_data['image_filename'],
                path=os.path.join('data', 'images', annotation_data['image_filename']),
                width=annotation_data['image']['width'],
                height=annotation_data['image']['height'],
                polygons=polygons
            )


    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        """Generate instance masks for an image.
    Returns:
        masks: A bool array of shape [height, width, instance count] with
            one mask per instance.
        class_ids: a 1D array of class IDs of the instance masks.
        """
        # If not a kangaroo dataset image, delegate to parent class.
        image_info = self.image_info[image_id]
        if image_info["source"] != "kangaroo":
            return super(self.__class__, self).load_mask(image_id)

        # Convert polygons to a bitmap mask of shape
        # [height, width, instance_count]
        # info = self.image_info[image_id]
        mask = np.zeros([
            image_info["height"],
            image_info["width"],
            len(image_info["polygons"])],
                        dtype=np.uint8)
        for i, p in enumerate(image_info["polygons"]):
            # Get indexes of pixels inside the polygon and set them to 1
            rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(p['ys'], p['xs'])
            mask[rr, cc, i] = 1

        # Return mask, and array of class IDs of each instance. Since we have
        # one class ID only, we return an array of 1s
        return mask.astype(np.bool), np.ones([mask.shape[-1]], dtype=np.int32)

    def image_reference(self, image_id):
        """Return the path of the image."""
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        if info["source"] == "kangaroo":
            return info["path"]
        else:
            super(self.__class__, self).image_reference(image_id)
```

I've tried to run this using:

```
python kangaroo.py train --dataset data/ --weights coco --logs logs/
```

My folder structure:

```
.
├── data
│   ├── annots
│   ├── coco
│   └── images
├── kangaroo.py
├── logs
└── requirements.txt
```

I've tried running this on the CPU of my mac (2018 15 inch model with 6-core i7)  and it seems to work, but although my CPU is running with fans making sounds as if it is about to take off the terminal always stays at the first epoch. I've run this for about an hour to 90 minutes and the terminal remains at:

```
Epoch 1/100
```

I thought this might be a hardware issue so I moved to a VM in the cloud (azure NC6 with a Nvidia Tesla K80 GPU with 12 GB of memory). When I run the model there it still remains at the first epoch (After I'd say at least 20 to 30 minutes).

First it seemed like it couldn't use the GPU because of the NVIDIA driver software being 10.1 will tensorflow was looking for 10.0. I downgraded to 10.0 and seemed to be working, however it still seems to hang at

```
epoch 1/100
```

The output I get

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Weights:  coco
Dataset:  data/
Logs:  logs/

Configurations:
BACKBONE                       resnet101
BACKBONE_STRIDES               [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
BATCH_SIZE                     2
BBOX_STD_DEV                   [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
COMPUTE_BACKBONE_SHAPE         None
DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES        100
DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE       0.8
DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD        0.3
FPN_CLASSIF_FC_LAYERS_SIZE     1024
GPU_COUNT                      1
GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM             5.0
IMAGES_PER_GPU                 2
IMAGE_CHANNEL_COUNT            3
IMAGE_MAX_DIM                  1024
IMAGE_META_SIZE                14
IMAGE_MIN_DIM                  800
IMAGE_MIN_SCALE                0
IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE              square
IMAGE_SHAPE                    [1024 1024    3]
LEARNING_MOMENTUM              0.9
LEARNING_RATE                  0.001
LOSS_WEIGHTS                   {'rpn_class_loss': 1.0, 'rpn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_class_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_mask_loss': 1.0}
MASK_POOL_SIZE                 14
MASK_SHAPE                     [28, 28]
MAX_GT_INSTANCES               100
MEAN_PIXEL                     [123.7 116.8 103.9]
MINI_MASK_SHAPE                (56, 56)
NAME                           Custom
NUM_CLASSES                    2
POOL_SIZE                      7
POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE        1000
POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING         2000
PRE_NMS_LIMIT                  6000
ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO             0.33
RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS              [0.5, 1, 2]
RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES              (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)
RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE              1
RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV               [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD              0.7
RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE    256
STEPS_PER_EPOCH                100
TOP_DOWN_PYRAMID_SIZE          256
TRAIN_BN                       False
TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE           200
USE_MINI_MASK                  True
USE_RPN_ROIS                   True
VALIDATION_STEPS               50
WEIGHT_DECAY                   0.0001


WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:442: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:58: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3543: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3386: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1768: The name tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.image.resize_nearest_neighbor instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1154: calling reduce_max_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1188: calling reduce_sum_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py:1475: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mask_rcnn-2.1-py3.7.egg/mrcnn/model.py:553: The name tf.random_shuffle is deprecated. Please use tf.random.shuffle instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mask_rcnn-2.1-py3.7.egg/mrcnn/utils.py:202: The name tf.log is deprecated. Please use tf.math.log instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mask_rcnn-2.1-py3.7.egg/mrcnn/model.py:600: calling crop_and_resize_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) with box_ind is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
box_ind is deprecated, use box_indices instead
Loading weights  data/coco/mask_rcnn_coco.h5
WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:153: The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:158: The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:163: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

2019-12-30 15:31:50.050404: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-12-30 15:31:50.057727: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2596990000 Hz
2019-12-30 15:31:50.058553: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55d9bb43b7f0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2019-12-30 15:31:50.058580: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2019-12-30 15:31:50.061043: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-12-30 15:31:54.571132: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55d9bb50c1d0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2019-12-30 15:31:54.571172: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
2019-12-30 15:31:54.571963: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: f923:00:00.0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.572242: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.573457: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.574598: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.574896: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.576375: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.577490: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.579974: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-12-30 15:31:54.581303: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.581360: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.584499: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-12-30 15:31:54.584536: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0
2019-12-30 15:31:54.584550: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N
2019-12-30 15:31:54.585941: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10805 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: f923:00:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:333: The name tf.global_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:341: The name tf.variables_initializer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer instead.

Training network heads

Starting at epoch 0. LR=0.001

Checkpoint Path: logs/custom20191230T1531/mask_rcnn_custom_{epoch:04d}.h5
Selecting layers to train
fpn_c5p5               (Conv2D)
fpn_c4p4               (Conv2D)
fpn_c3p3               (Conv2D)
fpn_c2p2               (Conv2D)
fpn_p5                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p2                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p3                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p4                 (Conv2D)
In model:  rpn_model
    rpn_conv_shared        (Conv2D)
    rpn_class_raw          (Conv2D)
    rpn_bbox_pred          (Conv2D)
mrcnn_mask_conv1       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn1         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv2       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn2         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv1      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn1        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv3       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn3         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv2      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn2        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv4       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn4         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_bbox_fc          (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_deconv      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_logits     (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask             (TimeDistributed)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py:711: The name tf.train.Optimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer instead.

/data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/indexed_slices.py:424: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
/data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/indexed_slices.py:424: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
/data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/indexed_slices.py:424: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:899: The name tf.assign_add is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign_add instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:625: calling Constant.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:886: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:705: The name tf.summary.merge_all is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.merge_all instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:708: The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead.

/data/anaconda/envs/mrcnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:1987: UserWarning: Using a generator with `use_multiprocessing=True` and multiple workers may duplicate your data. Please consider using the`keras.utils.Sequence class.
  UserWarning('Using a generator with `use_multiprocessing=True`'
Epoch 1/100
```

I looked at the gpu stats (nvidia-smi) and it seems the GPU uses almost al of it memory (say 95% of the 12 gb) but utilization is at 0%. This leads me to think that the model isn't running and is hanging somehow.

Am I being to impatient and does it take more than 30 minutes for a single epoch on a GPU (then why is the GPU utilization not high?) or is it really hanging?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: omg, i'm experiencing the exact same issue. I'm very new to ml so have no idea what's going on. any luck after 10 months?

Comment: Hi, @Neekey, we got it working but I can't remember what we changed. What's your code?

Comment: also same issue - any luck with finding the changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) to train your model.

Here is the link to the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16jcaJoc6bCFAQ96jDe2HwtXj7BMD_-m5) tutorial. Do note that your annotations should be in COCO format to train using Detectron2.